# Levy's Martingale Using Radon Nikodym

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Let P and Q be two probability measures on the same space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{P})$ and let $\mathcal{F_n}$ be filtration. Assume that $Q \ll P$. Let $X_n$ denote the Radon-Nikodym derivative of Q with respect to P on $\mathcal{F_n}$ i.e  $X_n$ is $\mathcal{F_n}$-measurable and for any $A \in \mathcal{F_n}$, $Q(A) = \int_AX_ndP$. Show that $(X_n,\mathcal{F_n})$ is a martingale with respect to P, that is $E_P(X_n|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}) = X_{n-1},$ where for any random variable X, $E_P(X) = \int XdP$.

To Prove $(X_n,\mathcal{F_n})$ martingale

i) $X_{n}$ is $\mathcal{F_{n}}$ - measurable.

ii) $E[|X_n|] <\infty$

ii) $E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F_{n}}] = X_n$

what I don't understand what is the mean of $(X_n,\mathcal{F_n})$ is a martingale with respect to P, that is $E_P(X_n|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}) = X_{n-1},$

Can you help me please?

Comment: Both properties ii) and iii) depend on a probability measure, so when one is saying "a martingale with respect to P" we mean that all expectations and conditional expectations are with respect to the probability measure P.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification can you help me start the prove please as I am not sure why we need Q and P here

Answer (score 1):

Measurability and integrability is a consequence of the Radon-Nikodym theorem. Since $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}\subseteq\mathcal{F}_n$ we have that 
$$
\int_AX_{n-1}\,\mathrm dP=Q(A)=\int X_n\,\mathrm dP
$$
for all $A\in\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$ showing that ${\rm E}_P[X_n\mid\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]=X_{n-1}$.

Comment: Thank for the help is this all the answer or I still have to prove something

Comment: What do you think? Have you shown that properties i), ii) and iii) are satisfied?

Comment: No I don't think this enough. Can you please help? As I am new to martingale and measure

Comment: What do you think is missing? Which of the properties i)-iii) is not clear to you?

Comment: Can some one Explain this question please

Comment: If $A\in\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$, then since $Q\ll P$ on $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$ we have $Q(A)=\int_A X_{n-1}\,\mathrm dP$. But since $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}\subseteq\mathcal{F}_n$ we have $A\in\mathcal{F}_n$ and the same reasoning gives that $Q(A)=\int_A X_n\,\mathrm dP$.

Comment: But how is this shows that $E_p(X_n|F_n) = X_{n-1}$

Comment: It doesn't. It shows that ${\rm E}[X_n\mid\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]=X_{n-1}$. To realize this, you need to take a look at the _definition_ of a conditional expectation. What must $X_{n-1}$ satisfy in order to be the conditional expectation ${\rm E}[X_n\mid \mathcal{F}_n]$?

Comment: $X_{n-1}$ must be $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$ - measurable then $X_{n-1}=E[X_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]$ but I still didn't get the relation between this and $E_p[X_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]$

Comment: ${\rm E}_P[\cdot\mid \cdot]$ just means that it is conditional expectation with respect to the probability measure $P$. By now, you should know that conditional expectations (just as ordinary expectations) depend on a probability measure.

Comment: Here's an exercise for you. Find out what you have to show in order to conclude that ${\rm E}_P[X_n\mid\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]$ (look at the definition of conditional expectation!). When you have written down the properties you need to show, then tell me which of the properties you can't see holds.

Comment: And then you're done. This shows that ${\rm E}[X_n\mid\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]=X_{n-1}$.

Comment: But I have question for property ii) there is absolute value so I am confused if it equal 1

Comment: The Radon-Nikodym theorem says that $X_n$ is non-negative, hence $|X_n|=X_n$.